# Magento - Store Config only added to database after being saved

Tags: magento

I have noticed that in Magento the core_config_data table is very small just after installation and it gradually gets populated over time ONLY when sections of the system config are saved.  For example there are no values in the core_config_data table for the contacts settings - yet i can still do Mage::getStoreConfig('contacts/contacts/enabled') and get the correct value.

So, does this mean that magento is simply reading the config xml until a value is saved, and at which point it saves to the database and then the value is read from there?

If this is the case, then surely this is a bad design pattern, having these values stored in two places?

Comment: Yes it is a bad design template. Magento has so many things that are bad with it.. but it is still a great e-commerce app. So what is the question exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this post may help.

[The Magento Config: Loading System Variables](http://alanstorm.com/magento_loading_config_variables)